# Installing samsung galaxy s3 neo stock rom on ssamsung galaxy s3

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-3

can I install samsung galaxy s3 neo (GT-I9300I) ROM on Samsung galaxy s3 (GT-I9300)....
If yes then please tell me how?

Comment: Sorry, but you can't install a ROM for one device/model on another one. Otherwise those ROMs would be unnecessary.

Comment: I want to install kitkat on GT-I9300... but not Cynogenmod based I want a rom similar to samsung stock rom... there is only one rom like that but it has many bugs... (galaxy s5 Project for galaxy s3)...
please give me any suggestions...

Comment: If you want a stock-like ROM, you can try searching at http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/development. For example Blekota Note 4 Lite (http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/development/rom-blekota-note-4-lite-v1-t2949680). Look for [TW] or [STOCK]

Comment: many many thanx... :-D

Comment: If any answer was found to your question, please do not post it in the comments section. Post it as an answer, and if the answer is correct, upvote that answer, instead of adding comments that thank other people. Please uphold and follow the rules of this site.

Comment: `If yes then please tell me how?` -- Even if it is possible somehow to install a ROM into the said device, it would be good if you search Google for the steps. That way, you'll learn a lot and will help you to move forward. More so, if you face difficulty in executing those steps which cannot be solved easily by querying Google, then gladly come back here. We'll be glad too :)